# Use regex to find 2 params in URL

Tags: regex

I'm setting up an AB test and I don't want certain pages, to be included in my AB test based on the query params in the URL.

I want to use regex to find two params in this URL:

- If the param begins with `&rooms`
- And if the second param begins with `&offerRooms`

  https://www.website.com?
  search=true
  &to=21-12-2020
  &from=14-01-2021
  &rooms[0][adults]=2
  &rooms[0][b]=0
  &rooms[0][c]=0
  &Id1=xxx
  &Id2=xxx
  &accId=abc
  &voucherCode=123
  &boardType=HB
  &offerRooms[0][adults]=2
  &offerRooms[0][b]=0
  &offerRooms[0][c]=0
  &dest=0

I have the following regex to find `&rooms[0][adults]=2`:

```
(rooms)\W0\W\Wadults\W=[2-9]
```

But I'm not sure how to expand this, to also look for and match `&offerRooms[0][adults]=2`

Essentially, I want my regex to find both of this params in one regex lookup.

Any pointers would be helpful!

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of what it is you want to do.
This regex will find `rooms[0][adults]=2` and `offerRooms[0][adults]=2`.
Is that what you're looking for?

```
(rooms|offerRooms)\[0\]\[adults\]=[2-9]
```

If you only want the urls that contain both and rooms always comes before offerRooms it is straight forward.

```
rooms\[0\]\[adults\]=[2-9].*offerRooms\[0\]\[adults\]=[2-9]
```

If you only want the urls that contain both and rooms doesn't always come before offerRooms it is rather complicated and requires a lookahead. Here I look for rooms if followed by offerRooms OR offerRooms if followed by rooms.

```
(rooms\[0\]\[adults\]=[2-9](?=.*offerRooms\[0\]\[adults\]=[2-9])|offerRooms\[0\]\[adults\]=[2-9](?=.*rooms\[0\]\[adults\]=[2-9]))
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for! I want to make sure the regex only works though, if the URL contains these params.

I noticed in a regex URl checker website, that if I remove one param, it still finds the other.  But I only want the regex to find the params, if they both exist in the URL.